# MongoDB Atlas works on localhost but not on production (NextJs on Vercel)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, vercel

I connected my `NextJs` app with `MongoDB Atlas`. It is working fine on localhost but it doesn't work on `Production hosted on Vercel`.

At first, I thought it's about network access and added `0.0.0.0/0 on the IP Access List` but no difference. The error `500` is only being shown on the production.

I have called the nextjs's api from Formik's form submit. On console, I also see this `Error at onSubmit (test-2b8b0b9f0ee833a8.js:1:14850)`

The codes for connect and disconnect

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connection = {};

async function connect() {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    console.log('already connected');
    return;
  }
  if (mongoose.connections.length > 0) {
    connection.isConnected = mongoose.connections[0].readyState;
    if (connection.isConnected === 1) {
      console.log('use previous connection');
      return;
    }
    await mongoose.disconnect();
  }
  const db = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
  console.log('new connection');
  connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
}

async function disconnect() {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      await mongoose.disconnect();
      connection.isConnected = false;
    } else {
      console.log('not disconnected');
    }
  }
}

function convertDocToObj(doc) {
  doc._id = doc._id.toString();
  doc.createdAt = doc.createdAt.toString();
  doc.updatedAt = doc.updatedAt.toString();
  return doc;
}

const db = { connect, disconnect, convertDocToObj };
export default db;
```

Person Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    count: { type: Number, required: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Person = mongoose.models.Person || mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
export default Person;
```

pages/api/my-endpoint.js

```
import db from '../../../mongoose/db';
import Person from '../../../mongoose/models/Person';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  // the codes

  await db.connect();
  let person = await Person.findOne({
    name: 'Frank',
  });
  person.count += 1;
  await type.save();
  await db.disconnect();

  // the codes
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Have you added the mongo db link in the vercel environment variable as MONGODB_URI of that project? Because vercel don't use .env file in the production.

Comment: Yes, I have added the same env key 'MONGODB_URI' and value on Vercel.

Comment: env name: MONGODB_URI,
env value: mongodb+srv://mycluster:mypassword@cluster.ydvarvg.mongodb.net/mydbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority

`This is how I added env on Vercel`

Comment: That environment variables section is present in the Settings when you open your project in the Vercel dashboard? Right.

Comment: Sure, it's under particular-project/settings/Environment Variables. I set above env name and value to all envs (production, preview, and development).

Comment: and also this has to be like this - const Person = mongoose.models?.Person || mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);  notice the question mark before .Person because in the production I was getting the error like Mongoose model not found, so I solved it like this.

Comment: I just tested that and there is no difference. The error keeps showing.

Comment: Can you show the whole or main part of the error message you are getting, its hard to guess with the one you provided above.

Comment: These are only two things I see on the console. `1. test-2b8b0b9f0ee833a8.js:1          POST https://staging.example.com/api/result 500` & `2. Error
    at onSubmit (test-2b8b0b9f0ee833a8.js:1:14850)`

Comment: Bro have you added env name: MONGODB_URI like this or only MONGODB_URI? The last one is correct and also are you returning the res.status(200).json(anyResult) in your api?

Comment: This is exactly what I copied from Vercel Env `MONGODB_URI`. I get this error on the console `2. Error     at onSubmit (test-2b8b0b9f0ee833a8.js:1:14850)`.

Comment: And that above error comes from this. `if (!res.ok) {
            const error = await res.text();
            throw new Error(error);
          }`

Comment: In API route, I returned like this `return res.send({
    status: 200,
    message: 'it works'
  });`. That's why it's all working fine on localhost I guess. I did the same with WP API and Laravel in the past and they are all working fine on both local and production.

Comment: I have posted an answer the one complete process down below that I followed in my multiple next js project.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I'm doing you can also try or modify --

/lib/dbConnect.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const DB_URL = process.env.DB_URL

if (!DB_URL) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the DB_URL environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    console.log("--- db connected ---");
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    }

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(DB_URL, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      console.log("--- db connected ---")
      return mongoose
    })
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  console.log("--- db connected ---")
  return cached.conn
}

export default dbConnect;
```

/models/videos.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let videoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  videoID: {
    type: String,
  },
  authorID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  authorName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  videoURL: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});
const Videos =mongoose.models?.videos || mongoose.model("videos", videoSchema);
export default Videos;
```

/pages/api/getVideos.js

```
import dbConnect from "../../lib/dbConnect";
import Videos from "../../models/videos";

export default async function handler(req,res){
    try{
        await dbConnect();
        await Videos.find().lean().then(response=>{
            return res.status(200).json(response);
        });
    }catch(e){
        res.status(400).json(e);
    }
}
```

//api calling method

```
 export const fetcher = (url,method,payload) => 
    fetch(url,{
    method:method,
    headers:{
    Accept:'application/json',
    'Content-Type':"application/json"
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(payload)
}).then(res=>{
    if(!res.ok){
        const error = new Error("Error while fetching the data");
        error.status = res.ok
        error.message = 'error'
        return error;
    }else{
        return res.json();
    }
})
```